# Scanner.hasNext() returns false

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have directory with many files in it - each with over 800 lines in it. Hovewer, when I try to read it using Scanner, it seems empty.

```
File f1 = new File("data/cityDistances/a.txt"),
     f2 = new File("data/cityDistances/b.txt");
System.out.println(f1.exists() && f2.exists()); //return true
System.out.println(f1.getTotalSpace() > 0 && f2.getTotalSpace() > 0); //return true
Scanner in = new Scanner(f1);
System.out.println(in.hasNext()); // return false;
System.out.println(in.hasNextLine()); //return false;
```

Why can it behave like that?

---

I've managed to do it using `BufferedReader`. Nonetheless, it seems even more strange that `BufferedReader` works and `Scanner` didn't.

Comment: This is going to sound dumb, but I have to check. I see that you are using .txt files. is there actually (readable, non-encrypted) text in those files? Is this text plaintext (as opposed to unicode)?

Comment: Also, sorry, I see "cityDistances" which makes me wonder. Could you try: hasNextInt(), hasNextDouble(), hasNextFloat(), hasNextBoolean(), and hasNextByte()? Your code looks like it should work; I'm just trying to help debug :)

Comment: I tried your code out with two random text files I had and it worked fine. Do you have a link to a sample file we could see?

Comment: Maybe you don't have permissions to read those files?

Comment: canRead() on file returns true.

Comment: as of the nextDouble() - content of the file matches this pattern - "name distance", so nextDouble wouldn't work

Comment: Anton, when I did it earlier, it worked. Now I've created a runnable jar, and it denies reading it.

Answer (score 7):

As the default delimeter for Scanner is whitespace, that would imply your `a.txt` contains only whitespace - does it have 800 lines of whitespace? ;)

Have you tried the following?

```
new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("a.txt")));
```

Comment: This did the trick, though I am not sure why,my file was pretty huge, 19MB containing data(not whitespace), and it abruptly cut off when I was just using the scanner

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem today reading a file with Scanner.
I specified the encoding type of the file and it solved the problem.

```
scan = new Scanner(selectedFile,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Answer (score 4):

This also happened to me today. I'm reading a plain text file from a Linux system written by some application in a Windows box and `Scanner.hasNextLine()` is always false even tough there are lines with the Windows line separator and all. As said by Hound Dog, by using

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)));
```

it worked like a charm. FileReader or BufferedReader seem to properly identify and use some file characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the scanner's exception may show that the file can't be read.

```
...
System.out.println(in.hasNext()); // return false;
IOException ex = in.ioException();
if (ex != null)
  ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The function File.getTotalSpace() is not behaving how you're expecting. It is returning the size of the partition where those particular files are located.

You want to use File.length().

Answer (score 0):

refer to file address you are using linux, refer to your name there is possible some Polish or Czech character and refer to below link, scanner dont like non utf-8  characters on linux:)

http://karussell.wordpress.com/2008/09/04/encoding-issues-solutions-for-linux-and-within-java-apps/

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't answer the OP's question, but for anyone else who is experiencing "my iterator's hasNext() is always false!"--if you have a bunch of watches with .next() in them, your IDE or whatever is actually advancing the cursor position per each one. This has caused me much trouble. Be careful with iterators and watches.