# why is Scanner's hasNext() method initially returning false for a non-empty text file?

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to write some text to a file. I have a while loop that is supposed to just take some text and write the exact same text back to the file.

I discovered that the while loop is never entered because Scanner thinks there's no more text to read. But there is.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WriteToFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String whatToWrite = "";

        File theFile = new File("C:\\test.txt");

        Scanner readinput = new Scanner(theFile);

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(theFile);

        while (readinput.hasNext()) { //why is this false initially?

            String whatToRead = readinput.next();

            whatToWrite = whatToRead;

            output.print(whatToWrite);
        }

        readinput.close();
        output.close();

    }

}
```

The text file just contains random words. Dog, cat, etc.

When I run the code, text.txt becomes empty.

There was a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495850/scanner-hasnext-returns-false which pointed to encoding issues. I use Windows 7 and U.S. language. Can I find out how the text file is encoded somehow?

**Update:**

Indeed, as Ph.Voronov commented, the PrintWriter line erases the file contents! user2115021 is right, if you use PrintWriter you should not work on one file. Unfortunately, for the assignment I had to solve, I had to work with a single file. Here's what I did:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WriteToFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<String> theWords = new ArrayList<String>();

        File theFile = new File("C:\\test.txt");

        Scanner readinput = new Scanner(theFile);

        while (readinput.hasNext()) {

            theWords.add(readinput.next());

        }

        readinput.close();

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(theFile); //we already got all of
            //the file content, so it's safe to erase it now

        for (int a = 0; a < theWords.size(); a++) {
            output.print(theWords.get(a));
            if (a != theWords.size() - 1) {
                output.print(" ");
            }
        }

        output.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(theFile);
```

It erases your file.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read the file using SCANNER and writing to another file using PRINTWRITER,but both are working on same file.PRINTWRITER clear the content of the file to write the content.Both the class need to work on different file.