# Scanner hasNext() method and escape characters

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I am trying to determine whether the next token in my `Scanner` contains a certain string. But, if there is a \n or \r in the token, the `hasNext(String)` method returns false no matter what.  (I am using Eclipse.)

The problem does NOT occur with default delimiter (a space). But if useDelimiter() is used - even to set the delimiter to " " - then hasNext(String) always returns false.

Does the `Scanner` `hasNext(String)` method always return false if there are escape characters somewhere in the token and the delimiter was also reset?

```
import java.util.*;

public class ScannerDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner("abcdefg\n\rX");
        scanner.useDelimiter("X");

        // Returns false!! Why?
        System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext(".*c.*"));
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        scanner.close();

        scanner = new Scanner("abcde\n\rXfg");
        scanner.useDelimiter("X");

        // Returns false!! Why?
        System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext(".*c.*"));
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        scanner.close();

        scanner = new Scanner("\n\rabcdeXfg");
        scanner.useDelimiter("X");

        // Returns false!! Why?
        System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext(".*c.*"));
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        scanner.close();

        scanner = new Scanner("abcdeXfg\n\r");
        scanner.useDelimiter("X");

        // Returns true, as expected
        System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext(".*c.*"));
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        scanner.close();

        scanner = new Scanner("abcdeXfg");
        scanner.useDelimiter("X");

        // Returns true, as expected
        System.out.println("" + scanner.hasNext(".*c.*"));
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");

        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` regex wildcard character does not match `\r` and `\n` by default.

You need to specify flag [`DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), but since you're not using the `Pattern` class directly, do it by adding `(?s)` to your regex:

```
scanner.hasNext("(?s).*c.*")
```

As the `DOTALL` javadoc says it:

> In dotall mode, the expression `.` matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators.

This is also covered by the description of the `.` in the javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef):

> `.`       Any character (may or may not match [line terminators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt))

The link says:

> The regular expression `.` matches any character except a line terminator unless the `DOTALL` flag is specified.

Comment: Adding '(?s)' to the regex certainly does the trick. I still don't understand why the \r\n should cause a problem - those aren't the characters I'm trying to match. And I'm not sure why 'useDelimiter()' should affect matters.

Comment: @MaeWarren When you specify `useDelimiter("X")`, the first token is `abcdefg\n\r`, so when you call `hasNext(".*c.*")`, the first `.*` matches `ab`, the `c` matches `c`, but the second `.*` doesn't match `defg\n\r`, *unless* `.` can match line terminators.

Comment: I see. I believe this fully answers the question. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495850/scanner-hasnext-returns-false). One of the answers there explains that:

"if you have a bunch of watches with .next() in them, your IDE ... is actually advancing the cursor position per each one." 
--Amalgovinus

This may be the problem you're encountering.

Comment: That's not it. The problem occurs only when there are escape characters in them. And the problem occurs before the first .next() executes.

Comment: Hm. I don't have an IDE handy right now (I'm on my phone), and I don't ever remember encountering that problem.